# Redireccionar despues de loguear a diferentes vistas por roles ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, login, redirección, users-roles

Estoy intentando que despues de loguear dependiendo del rol de la cuenta te redireccione a diferentes tipos de vistas dependiendo su rol. 
Asi funciona correctamente pero no redirecciona mas que solamente UNA vista:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(InputModelLogin model)
        {
            _model = model;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _user.UserLoginAsync(model);
                 if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    //Aqui es donde hace la redireccion
                    return Redirect("/");


            }

            else
            {
                _model.ErrorMessage = "Correo o contraseña inválidos.";
                return Redirect("/Login/Login");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    _model.ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
            return Redirect("/Login/Login");
        }
    }
```

Y asi es como queda el codigo cuando intento hacer la redireccion dependiendo del rol usando User.IsInRole, aqui es donde al darle al boton de iniciar sesión se salta todas las condicionales y directamente me manda al ultimo else que es el return redirect ("/") y no hace la redireccion debida:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(InputModelLogin model)
        {
            _model = model;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {   
                var result = await _user.UserLoginAsync(model);
                 if (result.Succeeded)
                {   //ROL 1
                    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                    {

                        return RedirectToAction("Admin", "AdminIndex");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //ROL 2
                        if (User.IsInRole("Profesor"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Profesores", "ProfesoresIndex");
                        }
                        else
                        {   //ROL 3
                            if (User.IsInRole("Alumno"))
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("Alumnos","AlumnosIndex");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Sin rol para que retorne un dato y no me de error
                                return Redirect("/");
                            }
                        }
                    }



                }

                else
                {
                    _model.ErrorMessage = "Correo o contraseña inválidos.";
                    return Redirect("/Login/Login");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                    {
                        _model.ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
                    }
                }
                return Redirect("/Login/Login");
            }
        }


 public async Task<IActionResult> Login(InputModelLogin model)
        {
            _model = model;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            var result = await _user.UserLoginAsync(model);
             if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                    {

                        return RedirectToAction("Admin", "AdminIndex");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (User.IsInRole("Profesor"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Profesores", "ProfesoresIndex");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (User.IsInRole("Alumno"))
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("Alumnos","AlumnosIndex");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Sin rol
                                return Redirect("/");
                            }
                        }
                    }



                }

                else
                {
                    _model.ErrorMessage = "Correo o contraseña inválidos.";
                    return Redirect("/Login/Login");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                    {
                        _model.ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
                    }
                }
                return Redirect("/Login/Login");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También se podría creando una pagina intermedia de bienvenida y desde esta Redireccionar según el rol

```
if(_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
var usuarioActual = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var buscarRole = usuarioActual != null && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(usuarioActual, "Administrator");
if(buscarRole)
{
    //Redireccionar a la pagina administracion
}
buscarRole = usuarioActual != null && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(usuarioActual, "Developer");
if(buscarRole)
{
    //Redireccionar a la pagina Desarrollador
}
buscarRole = usuarioActual != null && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(usuarioActual, "Blogs");
if(buscarRole)
{
    //Redireccionar a la pagina Blogs
}

...

}
```